# I have an error in django views.py file, httpresponse

Tags: django

This is my views.py file, in which i have create a small function.

> 

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
> 
> # Create your views here.
> 
> 
> def Index(request):
>     return HttpResponse("Danial")
```

This is my urls.py file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from api.views import Index

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', Index),
]
```

**This is Error**

Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/It%20is%20working...!
Using the URLconf defined in firstProject.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
The current path, It is working...!, didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

Comment: Did you tried this path: http://127.0.0.1:8000 ?

Comment: yes i tried this path

Comment: If you typed into your browser 127.0.0.1:8000 then everything should work. Please note that your error message refers to the link  http://127.0.0.1:8000/It%20is%20working. In this case it is expected that you are getting the error you described.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what can cause the problem but I see some mistakes in your code:

- Commonly used is to name methods with first lowercase charracter - first charracter uppervase is used ot name classes, so rename your method to index().
- urlpatterns in urls.py is a list so you shouldn't have that comma behind last member of list.

And just question: your app name is api? That is also sort of keyword and I wouldn't use it as an app name. If your app has other name, this can cause the problem so replace 'api' with your app name - with proper path in your folder structure.